# Increasing disk space on full node

Tags: polygon-pos

My Node disk space is continuously growing while running a Full Node is there a way to come this?

Also does Polygon support any support fast or light sync methods?

Tried restoring from snapshot.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So basically it is expected that the Blockchain Data grows day-to-day based upon the Transactional Flow.

For FullNode providers and Validator Node I would recommend to prune the nodes regularly and keep the disk space in check.

Steps to prune the node are in the following link

https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/pos/validator/kb/known-issues/#steps-to-prune-the-node

Alternatively you can also try to restore the data from snapshot make sure to use only the bulk-file for the pruned data.

https://snapshots.polygon.technology/